# How to merge custom auth with email and password

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I've custom auth on my backend. I can generate a token via this command

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(userUid);
```

however, when I use the token it is generated to login. It creates a new user in Firebase Auth with different uid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I realised I forgot to set uid when creating the user like this

```
 UserRecord.CreateRequest request = new UserRecord.CreateRequest()
            .setUid(mUser.getUid()) // need to set uid here to make sure it is the same in the our database
            .setEmail(mUser.getEmail())
            .setEmailVerified(false)
            .setPhoneNumber(mUser.getPhoneNumber())
            .setPassword(mUser.getPassword())
            .setDisplayName(mUser.getUsername())
            .setDisabled(false);
```